# save phone number by telegram-bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

the phone number for example it can be a password. if I have entered some data, I set the flag and then check it.
I don't know C# well (like English), I want to do it without static. Because this bot has many users, and if it is static, then it is one variable(state) for all users? Then I do SQL and check the user's password, login, etc. Maybe there is a better way to do it

```
 using System;
    using Telegram.Bot;
    using Telegram.Bot.Args;
    namespace TelegramBotConsole
    {
        class Program
        {
            static ITelegramBotClient botClient;
            static Boolean isTypePhone = false;
    
            static void Main()
            {
                string token = "token";
                botClient = new TelegramBotClient(token);
                var me = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;
                botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
                botClient.StartReceiving();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
                botClient.StopReceiving();
            }
    
            private static void Bot_OnReceiveError(object sender, ReceiveErrorEventArgs receiveErrorEventArgs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received error: {0} — {1}",
                receiveErrorEventArgs.ApiRequestException.ErrorCode,
                receiveErrorEventArgs.ApiRequestException.Message);
            }
            static async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
            {
                string typedText = e.Message.Text;
                if (typedText == "/start")
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: e.Message.Chat,
                    text: "type y'r phone number");
                    isTypePhone = true;
                }
                else if (isTypePhone == true)
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: e.Message.Chat,
                    text: $"your phone is { typedText }");
                    Console.WriteLine($"your phone is {typedText}");
                }
                else
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chatId: e.Message.Chat,
                    text: "error, hit the /start");
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: for example rewrite using switch case (switch statement does not change the variable outside case)

Comment: The problem here when multiple users is sending to the user at one time. The first sends: /start, And the other send the phone number. In this case you should store the case of everyone.